# Download on Mac, run on Windows

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

I have a Compaq Presario cq62 (Windows) laptop with a dead hard drive. I want to install Ubuntu on a USB to make it usable again. Can I download Ubuntu for Windows on my wife's MacBook, then create a boot USB to install the OS on my Windows laptop?

Comment: Basic answer - yes. It really does not matter where you make the installation USB/CD.  With dead hard drive,though, you won't install anything. Get a new hard drive, replace it, and install onto the new drive.

Comment: What is "Ubuntu for Windows"?

Comment: @Pilot6, it may refer to wubi,  no?

Comment: Sorry, Im new to Ubuntu. In hindsight, that was as dumb as saying "Windows for Mac". I just meant a version of Ubuntu that will run on a pc. So is there no way to just run Ubuntu from the USB drive, saving me the trouble and cost of a new hard drive? I'm only trying to extend the life of this laptop until I can get a new one in a year or two, so I don't want to sink a ton of money into it t.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to without problem. There is a few utilities out there that can format and setup your USB flash or external drive. One of the most popular tools seems to be Unetbootin. You can create a bootable USB from a wide variety of distributions that will work on just about any machine. You can check it out here: http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/